# noindexタグの付与方法について

Tags: php

phpページにnoindexタグを付与したいのですが質問があります。

単独で動作することがないphpはある部分の表示パーツとして、phpの中にはheadもbodyもありません。
複数のページから共通パーツとして呼び出されています。
このような場合、noindexをどのように付与するべきなのか分からないため、ご教示いただきたいです。

Comment: ページによって、noindexタグを出し分けをしたいということでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

ページが複数パーツに分かれているということであれば、headタグが含まれているphpファイルにnoindexを出力する処理を追加すればよいでしょう。おそらく特定のページのみnoindexを追加したいということだと思いますので、if文等で条件を指定し、noindexを出力するようにします。